# Volume growth on a locally symmetric space

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Consider a noncompact symmetric space $X=G/K$, where $G$ is the isometry group acting on $X$ (semisimple, noncompact, connected, with finite center) and $K$ the stabilizer of a fixed point $x_0\in X$. Let $n=\dim X$. Then, for every $x\in X$, for a small radius $r>0$, the volume growth of a geodesic ball $B_X(x,r)$ is $|B_X(x,r)|\sim r^n$.

Now, for a discrete, torsion free subgroup $\Gamma$ of $G$, the quotient $M=\Gamma \backslash G/K$ is a locally symmetric space, with the structure of a Riemannian manifold. Can we claim that for every $\tilde{x}\in M$ and a sufficiently small radius $r>0$, $|B_M(\tilde{x},r)|\sim r^n$?

Comment: Your question is unclear as it is missing several quantifiers. One way to interpret it is that for every $\tilde{x}\in M$ there exists $r(\tilde{x})$ and constants $C_1(\tilde x), C_2(\tilde x)$ such that for every $r\in (0, r (\tilde{x}))$, $C_1(\tilde{x})r^n \le Vol(B_M(\tilde{x}, r))\le r^n C_2(\tilde x) $. This has positive answer. But there are several other questions along the same lines which have negative answers. I suggest you revise the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate a bit more on cases with a negative answer? What I had in mind is for example  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374528?seq=16#metadata_info_tab_contents, p.1317, where the constants $C_1$, $C_2$ do not depend on $x$, for every, say, $r\leq 2$, and we have that polynomial volume growth. However, as far as I can tell, you suggest that in the case of locally symmetric spaces, as $r\rightarrow 0$, the constants are not universal.

Comment: It is a long and very technical paper and you should not expect me to figure out its relevance to your question. Your comment is still unclear, as I said, you should revise the question.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Gamma$ is discrete, than $M$ will have the same dimension as $X$, so the volume of small balls will have the same exponent in $r$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was what I suspected, but unfortunately couldn't find any reference in the literature to convince myself. I was also somewhat afraid of zero injectivity radius cases. If there is any reference that you could provide, I would be grateful.